# How to capture intermediate error in python subprocess's piped execution

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

Following python [doc](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) to replace shell-pipeline, I have a piece of code that looks like this.

```
p1 = Popen(["tac" , "/var/log/some_process_log.output"], stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["head", "-n", "1000"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=outfile)
p1.stdout.close()  # Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

`outfile` is where I want to redirect the output of `head` command. The log file is very large and hence I am doing a 'head' on it

The chaining is like `p1 | p2 | p3 | ..... | Pn > outfile`

If there's an error in execution of p1 e.g. the user does not have read permissions on the `/var/log/some_process_log.output` file, error message in `p1.stderr` is not piped through when I do `Pn.communicate()`

If I do p1.stderr.readline() at every stage, then it takes [long time to process](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects). This is mentioned in pydocs:

> Note The data read is buffered in memory, so do not use this method if
>   the data size is large or unlimited.

I am avoiding subprocess.check_output since it does not handle piping and plus it needs the unsafe `shell=True`

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could create a separate pipe with:

```
import os
errread, errwrite = os.pipe()
```

And set the write-end as the `stderr` for all your `Popen` instances:

```
p1 = Popen(["tac" , "/var/log/some_process_log.output"], stderr=errwrite, stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["head", "-n", "1000"], stdin=p1.stdout, stderr=errwrite, stdout=outfile)
```

Remember to close the write-end when it's done:

```
os.close(errwrite)
```

And get your error messages with either:

```
data_group = os.read(errread, buf_size)
```

or:

```
import io
data = io.open(errread, 'rb', buf_size).read()
```

Comment: Please note that, all error data is still buffered in memory.